# importrange to copy multiple spreedsheets in one using a loop to change the sources url

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

i'm trying to use a loop to use importrange with a var inside it, but i'm getting an error saying that there is a "formula parse error".

```
while (true) {
    var range = spreadsheet.getRange("Z" + i);
    var value = range.getValue();
    if(value == "") {
        break;
    }
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=importrange(value, "NOVO FUNIL!A20:T150")');
    i++;
```

It was supose to change the url and import the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't simply insert the variable inside the string, it'll take it as the literal string and not the value of the `value` variable.

Change this line:

```
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=importrange(value, "NOVO FUNIL!A20:T150")');
```

For this:

```
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=importrange(' + value + ', "NOVO FUNIL!A20:T150")');
```

Comment: it works! thanks, im really new in coding and i was pretty sure i was forgetting something but i couldn't see it.. rsrs. Thank u.